# Calculate Saturday Before X In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a need in Google Sheets to calculate the date of the Saturday prior to a given date.

e.g. If I were to give todays date of 16/04/17, it should return 15/04/17.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=A1-weekday(A1)
```

[weekday](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985)